# How to generate html elements with routerlink dynamically in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ui-router

I have self-referential model like the following.

```
export class Entity {
    constructor(public id: number,public name: string,public children: Entity[]) {
    }
}
```

And I want to create a tree list and every tree item will have a routerlink.

I wrote a recursive function which is generates all nodes with routerlinks. After that i have added the final html that i generated to master `<ul>` element.I am using JQuery to do this.

This is ngOnInit function.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.entityTree = this.fileOrganizationPlan.getEntityTree();
    let $body = $('.FileOrganizationPlan', this.el.nativeElement); //this is master <ul> element
    let html = { value: '' };
    this.generateNavScript(this.entityTree, html);
    $body.append(html.value);
  }
```

This is Recursive function which is generates tree items.

```
 generateNavScript(entityTree: Entity[], html) {

    for (let index = 0; index < entityTree.length; index++) {
      let entity = entityTree[index];
      html.value += `<li> <a  routerLink="/file-organization-plan/` + entity.id + `" >    </i> ` + entity.name + `</a>`;

      if (entity.children) {
        html.value += `<ul>`;
        this.generateNavScript(entity.children, html);
        html.value += `</ul>`;
      }

      html.value += `</li>`;

    }
  }
```

**Tree Items appears but routes are not working. I guess angular does not know this routerLink directives because of i added after rendering. Maybe i am missing something but i could't catch the point. So , what is the way to do this?**

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the same problem by checking the final compilation of the links created initially inside the template.

for example, this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/classes', name ]"></a>
```

Compile to this:

```
<a ng-reflect-router-link="/classes,name" href="/classes/name"></a>
```

so you can include the compile version on your component when you append html, like this:

```
generateNavScript(entityTree: Entity[], html) {

    for (let index = 0; index < entityTree.length; index++) {
      let entity = entityTree[index];
      html.value += `<li> <a  ng-reflect-router-link="/file-organization-plan, ` + entity.id + `" href="/file-organization-plan/`  + entity.id + `">    </i> ` + entity.name + `</a>`; 

      if (entity.children) {
        html.value += `<ul>`;
        this.generateNavScript(entity.children, html);
        html.value += `</ul>`;
      }

      html.value += `</li>`;

    }
  }
```

Comment: This will most likely case full page reload

Answer (score 1):

As you surmised, you can't add the routerLink dynamically - it's too late.

I would investigate creating a navigation component to replace your generateNavScript function.

Inside that component, do whatever you need to do to create a model of the links (perhaps using a modified version of the generateNavScript function). This model should be a simple list.

Then, in the component's template, use ngFor to iterate the list and create the routerLinks

Comment: Actually first i did like this. but in this case, the problem is i don't know how many level exist in Entity model Tree. So i should loop for Entity[] array and Entity.Children[] also and if exist Entity.Children[0].Children[]  i should loop also for their children. it goes like this. I couldn't do this with ngFor actually.

Comment: Right. I'm suggesting that you use a recursive function in your component to build the tree, and then traverse it to build an array from it. Then use that array in your ngFor